# Is there an instituted method for efficiently forming judgement?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

*"Critical thinking is the objective analysis of facts to form judgement."*- Wiki

is there any instituted method for efficiently forming judgement? Are there any notable bodies of work on the subject which I could do research on? Thank you.

Comment: Here is some more information on judgment and reasoning.  https://maritain.nd.edu/jmc/etext/psych015.htm

Comment: Plato dialogue Theaetetus: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-theaetetus/ am not suggesting that my two comments contain "the answer", I am just posting some material you may want to add to your collection if you don't have it already.

Comment: A judgement of fact ? A judgement of taste ? A subject-neutral judgement ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so long as one sticks to a discipline. For then there are acceptable canons and authorities by which one can make an informed and justified opinion. Within a discipline, taste and judgement is trained and trainable, though the extent it can be so done is obviously dependent on an individual talents, capacities and opportunities.

Comment: *”...so as long as one sticks to a discipline.”*, I think I read about that. Does that mean the methods of properly reaching a judgment in one field/discipline may differ from methods in another?

Comment: @Iam Pye: I would think so. How one practically trains the mind, eye and hand as an artist is very different to how one does so as a physicist. Though you can take a higher level view and say that both require canons, authorities and judgements by which one learns.

Comment: I agree with Mozibur. It's nice to have some general guidelines, but for instance law and art are very different. Law has worked out its own "ways", these ways are not common sense (they are uncommon common sense). Art you have the whole study of aesthetics, etc.

Comment: @Gordan: I  read something by Badiou a while ago where he said that European Art has run into the sands by fetishing the experimentation of form. I think Roberto Unger made a similar remark about modern literature.